Calculate expected value of a function of IID samples
Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $E[X] = \mu$. We define random variable $T$ that for every  IID sample $S = \{x_1,..., x_n\}$,  then $T(S) = \frac{1 + \sum\limits_1^n x_i}{n}$.
Although it is obvious that expected value of $T$ on all samples with size $n$ is $\mu + \frac{1}{n}$, but I do not know what is $E[T]$ which is relative to all possible samples, not only those that have same size?
Update:
Really this question raised in my mind when I read this section of a Wikipedia page:

an estimator can be biased but consistent. For example, if the mean is estimated by $\frac{1}{n} \sum x_i + \frac{1}{n}$ it is biased, ...

That question was: How can I calculate the expected value when it depends on $n$? How can I show that is not equal to $\mu$?

This is not clear.  There is no uniform distribution on the natural numbers so you need to clarify how $n$ is chosen.   You could cap the size, at $N$ say, solve the problem for samples of size $≤N$, and then try to let $N$ go to $\infty$ but it isn't clear if this sort of thing is what you have in mind.

Note:  Since $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n\sim \log N$, the procedure I described yields $\mu$ in the limit.  But, again, you might have something else in mind.

@lulu I updated my question. Please see that again.

I don't see where you responded to the point I made.  I note that that reference concludes the same thing I did...that in the large sample limit you do get $\mu$, but again it is not clear if that's what you had in mind.  As a practical matter, that limit doesn't tell you much.  It's still a biased estimator for any bounded sample size.

Data samples are defined with a fixed sample size $n$, i.e. $n$ is a constant in your problem. So $E(T)$ is exactly what you said, the expected value of T over all samples of size $n$.
The Wikipedia page states that the $E(T)$ is biased. The bias is $B(T) = E(T) - \mu = \frac{1}{n}$. The statistic $T$ is consistent because $B(T) \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.
